# Weird Crash only on iPhone 6+(symbolicated crash log)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, crash, iphone-6-plus

I am getting a weird crash on iPhone 6 +(only) running on iOS 8.4. The crash happens when I rotate the device. But my orientation methods looks fine. The crash is very inconsistent and there is no specific steps to reproduce it.

Below is my crash log:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  12

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1848ac2d8 __exceptionPreprocess + 132
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1965800e4 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   CoreFoundation                  0x184792f70 -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 412
3   CoreFoundation                  0x18479f200 +[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:] + 60
4   UIKit                           0x1895e9a84 _UIViewTopDownSubtreeTraversal + 148
5   UIKit                           0x189645ab8 -[UIViewController _replaceViewControllerInPresentationHierarchy:] + 164
6   UIKit                           0x1896459dc -[UIViewController _adaptedPresentationControllerForTraitCollection:withTransitionCoordinator:] + 564
7   UIKit                           0x18963001c -[UIPresentationController _sharedParent:willTransitionToTraitCollection:withTransitionCoordinator:] + 312
8   UIKit                           0x18962febc -[UIPresentationController _window:willTransitionToTraitCollection:withTransitionCoordinator:] + 44
9   UIKit                           0x18963faf0 -[UIViewController _window:willTransitionToTraitCollection:withTransitionCoordinator:] + 316
10  UIKit                           0x18963faf0 -[UIViewController _window:willTransitionToTraitCollection:withTransitionCoordinator:] + 316
11  UIKit                           0x1895e23c4 -[UIWindow _rotateToBounds:withAnimator:transitionContext:] + 340
12  UIKit                           0x1895e340c -[UIWindow _rotateWindowToOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:skipCallbacks:] + 1260
13  UIKit                           0x1895e3b0c -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:applyTransformToWindow:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 360
14  UIKit                           0x1893a2c30 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 144
15  UIKit                           0x189a19c0c -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _placeCounterRotationViewWithView:inWindow:fromOrientation:toOrientation:force:] + 296
16  UIKit                           0x189a19a70 -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _adjustOrientationIfNecessaryInWindow:forViewController:preservingViewController:] + 600
17  UIKit                           0x18962b3a8 -[UIPresentationController _dismissWithAnimationController:interactionController:target:didEndSelector:] + 444
18  UIKit                           0x189332b00 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 88
19  UIKit                           0x18964983c -[UIViewController _dismissViewControllerWithAnimationController:interactionController:completion:] + 624
20  UIKit                           0x189332b00 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 88
21  UIKit                           0x18944c34c -[UIViewController _dismissViewControllerWithTransition:from:completion:] + 936
22  UIKit                           0x1893f4388 -[UIViewController dismissViewControllerWithTransition:completion:] + 1036
23  UIKit                           0x182cac88c -[UIViewControllerAccessibility dismissViewControllerWithTransition:completion:] + 128
24  UIKit                           0x1893f3f1c -[UIViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:] + 252
25  UIKit                           0x182cac668 -[UIViewControllerAccessibility dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:] + 128

:

:

Thread 12 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196d43c78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196ddd2d8 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196ddceec start_wqthread + 0
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Set an exception breakpoint in your code and share the code that it's breaking on so we can help you please

Comment: It might be an auto layout related issue